# Pandas Copy Values from Rows to other files without disturbing the existing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, for-loop, merge

I have 20 csv files pertaining to different individuals.

And I have a Main csv file, which is based on the final row values in specific columns. Below are the sample for both kinds of files.

All Individual Files look like this:

> *alex.csv*

```
name,day,calls,closed,commision($)
alex,25-05-2019,68,6,15
alex,27-05-2019,71,8,20
alex,28-05-2019,65,7,17.5
alex,29-05-2019,68,8,20
```

> *stacy.csv*

```
name,day,calls,closed,commision($)
stacy,25-05-2019,82,16,56.00
stacy,27-05-2019,76,13,45.50
stacy,28-05-2019,80,19,66.50
stacy,29-05-2019,79,18,63.00
```

But the Main File(single day report), which is the output file, looks like this:

```
name,day,designation,calls,weekly_avg_calls,closed,commision($)
alex,29-05-2019,rep,68,67,8,20
stacy,29-05-2019,sme,79,81,18,63
madhu,29-05-2019,rep,74,77,16,56
gabrielle,29-05-2019,rep,59,61,6,15
```

I require to copy the required values from the columns(calls,closed,commision($)) of the last line, for end-of-today's report, and then populate it to the Main File(template that already has some columns filled like the {name,day,designation....}).

And so, how can I write a **for** or a **while** program, for all the csv files in the "Employee_performance_DB" list.

```
Employee_performance_DB = ['alex.csv', 'stacy.csv', 'poduzav.csv', 'ankit.csv' .... .... .... 'gabrielle.csv']
for employee_db in Employee_performance_DB:
    read_object = pd.read_csv(employee_db)
    read_object2 = read_object.tail(1)
    read_object2.to_csv("Main_Report.csv", header=False, index=False, columns=["calls", "closed", "commision($)"], mode='a')
```

> How to copy values of {calls,closed,commision($)} from the **'Employee_performance_DB'** list of files to the exact column in the **'Main_Report.csv'** for those exact empolyees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I had no answers for this, it took a while for me to find a solution.

The code below fixed my issue...

```
# Created a list of all the files in "employees_list"
employees_list = ['alex.csv', ......, 'stacy.csv']

for employees in employees_list:
    read_object = pd.read_csv(employees)
    read_object2 = read_object.tail(1)
    read_object2.to_csv("Employee_performance_DB.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```